# Anchor doesn't load on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor

So my website includes a two-part navigation, both points are anchors placed on the main site. I have added  On that site there are other links that lead to subsites. Now I have a hard time getting the same navigation points only on the subsites to load the anchors when going back to the main site where they are originally placed. Tried several methods found on the internet but none of that seemed working.

I also added a smooth scrolling with some jquery found on the internet, also tried to delete the prevent default line.

This is my site http://stefangloeggl.com, the subsites can be reached through clicking on one of the first pictures.

My markup looks something like this.

```
<a href="index.php#work">Work</a>
<a href="index.php#about">About</a>

<div name="work" id="work">
Work
</div>

<div name="about" id="about">
Biography
</div>
```

Would really appreciate some help on this one.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) where everyone can reproduce the error. This increases your chances of getting any help significantly.

Comment: I would create one, I just dont know of an option two create two html sites, which I would need to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite strange structure on your page. Your page markup seems to have body height/width 100% and your anchors are one inside another. 
Best solution is to make clean markup from scratch.

Fast but dirty solution is to add `window.location.hash` checking on document ready, then activate your smooth scroll.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (window.location.hash.length>1) {
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
  });
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Fixed the issue now with the second anchor inside the other one. Forgive me my inexperience but how do I trigger your script on a button press that happens on a different page? (I mean when the a-tag on page 1 gets pressed, will it trigger the chosen script on page 2?)

Comment: <script> 
     function aboutfunction() {  
    var varabout = document.getElementById("about");
varabout.scrollIntoView(true); };
    </script> I tried now to add something like this, it kinda works but after jumping to the right location it instantly switches to the top of the page.

Comment: This script will only work on pages where it is included, and script check hash-section of url. So if in page2 you have #someid in url it will works. 
I guess with your exp. you better youse some solution like http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ 

on plugin homepage you can find example of binding event(move code from my answer inside that event) and triggering it from other places.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Tried your suggested solution and found a way to make it work for me.